# User Input Verification Question in While Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, input, while-loop

I have the following code written so far, and it is giving me an error.

```
questions = [['pets', ['Dog', 'Cat']],
             ['siblings', ['Brother', 'Sister']],
             ['children', ['Son', 'Daughter']]]
result = {x: 0 for y in questions for x in y[1]}
for q in questions:
    while True:
        a = input(f'Do you have any {q[0]}? ').lower()
        if a in ['no', 'n']:
            b = input(F"You answered no. Is that correct?")
            if b in ['yes' 'y']:
                break
        if a not in ['yes', 'y']:
            b = input(F"You answered no. Is that correct?")
            continue
        else:
            b = input(F"You answered yes, is that correct?")
        for sq in q[1]:
            while True:
                a = input(f'How many {sq}s do you have? ')
                try:
                    b = input(F"You answered that {a}. Is that correct?")
                    if b = ["yes", "y"]:
                        n = int(a)
                    if n < 0:
                        raise ValueError
                    result[sq] += n
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print('Please only respond with positive numbers')
        break
for k, v in result.items():
    s = '' if v == 1 else 's'
    print(f'You have {v} {k}{s}')
```

I would like my code to running like below:

```
Do you have any pets? Yes
You answered "Yes". Is that correct? Yes 
How many dogs do you have? 2 
You answered "2". Is that correct? Yes 
How many cats do you have? 0 
You answered "0". Is that correct Yes
    
Do you have any siblings? Yes 
How many brother do you have? 1 
You answered "1". Is that correct? Yes 
How many sister do you have? 0 
You answered "0". Is that correct? Yes
    
Do you have any children? No 
You answered "No". Is that correct? Yes
    
Based on your response above, you have: 
2 dogs, 
0 cats, 
1 brother, 
0 sister,
0 children.
```

I am not sure how to put the confirmation question input below in my while loop as I have written on top.

"***you have entered {user_input}. Is that correct?***"

Comment: You probably want to make a dictionary out of `questions` and loop through it

Answer (score 0):

Have you run your code with a debugger?
This block should be indented:

```
if n < 0:
    raise ValueError
result[sq] += n
```

Besides you're not converting the input to `lower` consistently.

One last thing I noticed is that a comma is missing in the following statement:

```
if b in ['yes' 'y']:
```

Otherwise your code seem to do what you expect